# Removing string from within string

Tags: python

I am trying to remove part of a string withing a string. for example if a string is "atgtga" i want the output to be "atg".
i tried using the .replace("tga","") method but my TA was saying that it only masks that part of the string instead of removing it.

i tried a new approach but i am still stuck on the if statement.

```
x="atgtgaacttaa"
c=0
q=3

while(q<=len(x)):
    x=x[c:q]

    if(x=="tga" or x=="taa" or x=="tag"):

       c=c+3
       q=q+3

print(x)
```

I tried making a new function but my output is ignoring "atg" for some reason and deleting it.

```
 def get_orf(dna_seq):
   x=0

   while(x<=len(dna_seq)):
     if("taa" in dna_seq or "tag" in dna_seq or "tga" in dna_seq ):
       dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("taa","") 
       dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tag","") 
       dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tga","")
       return dna_seq
     else:
      return dna_seq
     x=x+1
```

Comment: Your TA is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use `replace`, sometimes things do what they say on the tin:

```
>>> x = "atgtga"
>>> y = x.replace("tga", "")
>>> print(y)
atg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TA is incorrect.  **replace** returns a *new* string with the indicated change.  The original string is, indeed, still intact, but the new string is a separate entity, not part of the original, and not dependent on the original any more.